# Share a variable among bash scripts

Tags: bash

I have 2 bash scripts:

set.sh

```
export MYVAR="MYVALUE"
```

get.sh

```
echo "MYVAR: $MYVAR"
```

usage

```
> ./set.sh && ./get.sh
```

I'm trying to share the variable among the scripts. The real code is more complicated and involves more than 2 scripts, so I cannot call the second script from the first one like that

```
export MYVAR="MYVALUE"
./get.sh
```

Comment: You can't share dynamically changing `bash` variables between scripts because they are generally separate processes. You *could* share by putting the value in **Redis** which is a *"data structure server"* that can share integers, strings, hashes, lists, sets, queues, atomics across processes and distributed servers.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of several tries:

1. Via third script: Use a third environment script and `source` it in set.sh and get.sh. Probably you can't do that because set.sh has a lot of logic.
2. Via code: `source` set.sh in get.sh and add specific logic to set.sh to recognize if set.sh is sourced or executed.
3. Via pipe: Have you thought about using a pipe for interprocess communication between set.sh and get.sh? You could send `MYVAR` from set.sh to get.sh through the pipe, and only start executing in get.sh once this information has arrived.
4. Via file: Use a file to transmit the value of `MYVAR` by writing it from set.sh to the file and reading from the file in get.sh.
5. Via output: Write `MYVAR` to the output in set.sh and consume (or parse) the output of set.sh in get.sh.

Answer (score -1):

Set them as arguments to the scripts

```
./set.sh "$MYVAR" && ./get.sh "$MYVAR"
```